# Create a gwt-maven archetype in eclipse

Tags: maven, gwt-maven-plugin, gwt-maven-archetypes

How to create and add a new archetype in eclipse (neon). I want to create gwt maven project in eclipse by selecting a archetype from 'Select a archetype' screen but i could not find the required archetype in the list although i have installed all the required plugins for GWT . Some of the solution says to create a gwt project and then convert it to maven and add required dependencies but i don't want to do that .Any ideas ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the solution... instead of creating a new archetype i imported maven remote archetype catalogs in eclipse ...Here's how i did it :

**Step 1** : Open maven preferences in eclipse
Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Maven -> Archetypes.

**Step 2** : Add a remote catalog file .Click on Add Remote Catalog button. Fill the catalog file as “**http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml**” and some custom description.

This will take a while to download all the required jars in your .m2 folder (this is a one time process)

**Step 3** : Now you can find gwt-maven-plugin entry in 'select a archetype' screen .Create a gwt-maven project with this archetype and you are set .